# Control update Android app programmatically in Google play

Tags: android, auto-update

I'm developing an application with a large data.
It takes a long time to upload/download to server (around 1 hour).

I'm understanding that:

- When uploading if having a new version up in Google Play, Android system will break uploading and update new app. Is my understanding ok?
- I want, my app doesn't update automatically. User must finish uploading before update a new version.

How to disable auto update option in Google App by programming?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13269731/6444297) may help you understanding why it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Im running as **root** and this command work for me:

```
adb shell pm disable-user com.android.vending
```

and then there is no Playstore on my andriod device.

for revert run this command:

```
 adb shell pm enable com.android.vending
```

if you  **not root** you can try:

```
adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 com.android.vending
```