# Android broadcast action

Tags: android, action, broadcast, malware

Someone know the full name of the broadcast action to know when a new application is installed on android ?

It is for an anti-malware on android.

Thanks.

Comment: try these links:

[How to receiving broadcast when application installed or removed][1]


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297149/android-listen-for-app-installed-upgraded-broadcast-message

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-receiving-broadcast-when-application-installed-or-removed

Answer (score 1):

How to easily find broadcast actions.

1. Go to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
2. Search key word (in this case, **install**).

Result:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL